# jQuery opposite of find()

Tags: jquery, find, parent

The following element:

```
<div class="hslide"></div>
```

contains a series of other elements and is repeated several times on a page.

Inside the content are triggers that interact with the element. At the moment the triggers cause the same thing to happen with all hslide elements.

ie.  `var current = $('.hslide .slide.current');`

Is there a way of selecting the correct .hslide because the trigger contained within it is contained within it. I could use parent() but the trigger is not always only one layer down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery.parent() doesn't appear to be working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754867/jquery-parent-doesnt-appear-to-be-working) and many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned to select the correct parent, so you should use `.closest()` to traverse up to the parent element:

```
var current = $('.slide.current').closest('.hslide');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `.closest(selector)`, which returns the innermost matching parent element.